# Connecting Power Apps Model-Driven Apps to SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server, etl, connector, dataverse

Trying to figure out the best way of managing data stored in an on-premise SQL Server database, for a Power Automate Model-Driven App. For Canvas Apps, typically I use a connector to either access the tables directly, or to access the data via a Power Automate flow.

From my research, it seems like I have two options:

1. Create Dataverse tables which represent all of my SQL Server tables, and use an ETL tool to keep those tables in sync.
2. Use a Virtual Table to connect "directly" to the SQL Server tables

Neither of those options really seem great, though. The entire premise of the Power Platform is for a relatively low-code experience, and both of those two options require quite a bit of coding. The ETL option, for example, requires me to write ETL operations for every table that I want to manage, along with dealing with any number of concurrency issues that may arise. The Virtual Table, on the other hand, seems on the surface like it'd be a better approach, but to actually implement a Virtual Table for an SQL Server table, I need to write a custom connector, and I need to leverage the old D365 UI to manage it.

The "best" approach I've seen so far is explored a bit by Juuka Niiranen in this blog post, however, a year later, and the approach he wrote about is still in preview: https://jukkaniiranen.com/2021/06/virtual-dataverse-tables-with-no-code-via-connectors/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/create-virtual-tables-using-connectors?tabs=sql

Does anyone have any other suggestions? Is that above connector approach the recommended one, despite still being in preview?

Comment: FWIW, low-code <> no-code.  In order to make low-code solutions usable it is frequently the case that you must do a bit of coding, especially when working with large datasets.

Comment: I've used virtual tables for various integrations - an external data source via a REST API, the list of Azure AD users from Azure AD , and more - worked quite nicely so far, I'd definitely look into this.

Comment: @marc_s have you specifically used the virtual table connector? or did you create your own custom connector for the virtual tables?

Comment: I created my own custom plugins for `RetrieveMultiple` and `Retrieve` from scratch - just readonly access for now.